# Need some help with testing

Tags: testing

I am new to testing so I am trying to test some random things that I found on the Internet. These are the test case that I thought for testing these things. Any help to assist me is very much appreciated.

1) Testing a text box.

```
Test cases:
Unit tests:
Passing alphabets from [a-z], [A-Z]
digits [0-9] , special symbols
test special characters specific to a language like \n etc

Stress tests:
To add a string as long as possible
```

Any other test cases are possible ? Do I need to test multiple text boxes too?

Comment: This reads a little like a homework question rather than a practical programming problem.  Maybe you could tell us a little more about what you're trying to accomplish with these tests, how you're planning to use the text boxes, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For general input testing:

- Test the **upper bounds** of your input: (max, max+1, max-1)
- Test the **lower bounds** of your input: (min, min-1, min+1)
- Test the **mid point** (max+min/2)
- Test **uncommon characters**: `!@#$%^&*()-=+_`;':"\|[]{},./<>?`  (<-- **see**: these chars break the StackOverflow HTML code parser )
- Test `unicode` characters
- Test **long** input strings
- Test **empty** / `null` input

Try these strings and see if your program crashes:

```
"%n"
"%x%x%x%n"
```

If you're using `printf()` the unsafe way it will crash.

Comment: +1 Good list, also try entering 0, 00, 001, ...

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your language, you might try passing `null` instead of a string.  You also want to pass Unicode strings with a bunch of weird characters.

Answer (score 1):

Along with all the functional type testing you mentioned, also consider testing for SQL Injection attacks.  Try entering actual commands into the text box.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Classic examples include entering

`' or '1'='1`

`' or '1'='1';/*'`

Which could yield a statement such as

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '' OR '1'='1';`